# How to get the javascript to execute to update the images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to resize the images using JavaScript. This example is based on a working jsfiddle, but the page does not seem to work. I presume the script in in the wrong place, but I could not find the correct one. How to put it right?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function loadImage() {
                $(this).attr('height', $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('imgheight'));
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div imgheight="300px" class="images">
            <div>
                <a> <img src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/goldenhorseman.jpg " onload="loadImage()"/></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a> <img src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bronze-horseman.jpg " onload="loadImage()"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Still does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(function() {
        $('.images div a img').on('load', function() {
            $(this).attr('height', $(this).closest('.images').data('imgheight'));
        });
    });

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div imgheight="300px" class="images">
            <div>
                <a> <img src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/goldenhorseman.jpg " /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a> <img src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bronze-horseman.jpg " /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**SOLUTION**

Needed to include jquery correctly; once I had, it works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $('.images div a img').on('load', function() {
            alert($(this).closest('.images').attr('imgheight'));
            $(this).attr('height', $(this).closest('.images').attr('imgheight'));
        });
    });
    </script>
<body>
    <body>
        <div imgheight="300px" class="images">
            <div>
                <a> <img src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/goldenhorseman.jpg " /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a> <img src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bronze-horseman.jpg "/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is loadImage() getting invoked? Also can you paste the link to fiddle where it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$(this).closest('.images').data('imgheight')` to `$(this).closest('.images').attr('imgheight')` if you want get value from attribute  just use `$.attr('get value attrb')`

```js
$(function() {
        $('.images img').on('load', function() {
            console.log($(this).closest('.images').attr('imgheight'))
            $(this).attr('height', $(this).closest('.images').attr('imgheight'));
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
      
    <body>
        <div imgheight="300px" class="images">
            <div>
                <a> <img src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/goldenhorseman.jpg " /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a> <img src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bronze-horseman.jpg "/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Started to work once I had included jquery correctly - see above.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because you are attaching your event handler using the `on*` attributes, the `this` reference in the function is not the element that raised the event but the `window`. You need to pass the reference to the function as a parameter.

Also note that you have several issue in your HTML. Firstly you can use `closest('.images')` instead of chained `parent()` calls, and the `imgheight` attribute is invalid. You should use a `data-*` attribute to store custom meta data with an element. Finally `a` elements must have either a `href` or `name` atttribute. With all that said, try this:

```
<div data-imgheight="300px" class="images">
    <div>
        <a href="#"> 
            <img src="http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/goldenhorseman.jpg" onload="loadImage(this)" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#"> 
            <img src="http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bronze-horseman.jpg" onload="loadImage(this)" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
function loadImage(el) {
    $(el).attr('height', $(el).closest('.images').data('imgheight'));
}
```

Alternatively a better approach would be to use unobtrusive Javascript to attach your event handlers. As you're already using jQuery, here's an example;

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        $('.images img').on('load', function() {
            $(this).attr('height', $(this).closest('.images').data('imgheight'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<img src="http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bronze-horseman.jpg" />
```

Finally note that the `data-imgheight` attribute will be set to the height of the `img` element which loaded last. If this is what you're intending to do, great, although it's a bit of an odd pattern to use.

Comment: There is no alternate for `parent().parent().parent()` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre yep, thanks. Was in the middle of editing in some extra suggestions.

Comment: Pleasure.. I would go with the `css` instead of `attr`..Not sure about better practices..

Comment: Thanks, I have tried all your suggestions, unfortunately the images still do not get resized. I have this html as a file on my machine and it works in neither Chrome nor Safari.

Comment: Why would the images be resized by this code? All you're doing is setting a `data` attribute (or a non-standard attribute in your original example)